# Grouping events in a timeline SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a series of events that follow each other in time sequence.  For ease, I am rounding the events to to 1 minute.  Sometimes the same event occur subsequent to the same event, essentially making it the same event.

The base data looks like this:

[image]

```
    create table #Events (StartTime datetime,EndTime datetime,Activity varchar(55)) insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 10:01','2017/09/19 10:15','Play' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 10:16','2017/09/19 11:00','Subject 1' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 11:01','2017/09/19 11:12','Subject 1' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 11:13','2017/09/19 11:15','Play' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 11:16','2017/09/19 11:25','Play' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 11:26','2017/09/19 12:14','Subject 2' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 12:15','2017/09/19 12:25','Subject 2' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 12:26','2017/09/19 12:35','Subject 2' insert into #Events (Start,End,Activity) select '2017/09/19 12:36','2017/09/19 12:45','Play'
```

I would like a result set that looks like this:
[image]

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a difference in row numbers to group the activity islands. For example:

```
SELECT Start = MIN(StartTime), [End] = MAX(EndTime), Activity
FROM (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Activity ORDER BY StartTime)
    FROM #Events
) AS E
GROUP BY Activity, RN;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the best way :

```
SELECT  X.Start, Y.[End], X.Activity
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E1.StartTime) RN, E1.StartTime [Start], E1.Activity
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) RN
        FROM #Events
    ) AS E1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) RN
        FROM #Events
    ) AS E2
    ON E1.Activity=E2.Activity
    AND E1.RN=E2.RN+1
    WHERE E2.Activity IS NULL
) X
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E1.StartTime) RN, E1.EndTime [End], E1.Activity
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) RN
        FROM #Events
    ) AS E1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) RN
        FROM #Events
    ) AS E2
    ON E1.Activity=E2.Activity
    AND E1.RN=E2.RN-1
    WHERE E2.Activity IS NULL
) Y
ON X.RN=Y.RN
```

result :

```
2017-09-19 10:01:00.000 2017-09-19 10:15:00.000 Play
2017-09-19 10:16:00.000 2017-09-19 11:12:00.000 Subject 1
2017-09-19 11:13:00.000 2017-09-19 11:25:00.000 Play
2017-09-19 11:26:00.000 2017-09-19 12:35:00.000 Subject 2
2017-09-19 12:36:00.000 2017-09-19 12:45:00.000 Play
```

Comment: Really clever solution! Thanks.